# PowerShell error when trying to install a software using Winget inside Python

Tags: python, powershell, winget

Error When trying to install a software using PowerShell inside Python.
with this command:
"command = ["winget", "install", "-e", "--id", "VideoLAN.VLC"]"

I get this error:
**"Found an existing package already installed"**
the software **was** installed before and I removed it manually.
the error appears only in the IDE, when running this command outside the IDE
it's working.

tried to install the software.

Comment: The error "Found an existing package already installed" in Winget installation via Python indicates that the software is already on the system, even after manual removal. Remedies include clearing Winget's cache to ensure a clean state and confirming complete removal of the software's remnants. Investigating IDE-specific settings and seeking community support can provide further insights. Overall, addressing this error involves troubleshooting steps like cache clearing, verifying complete removal, and alternative installation methods.

Comment: _I removed it manually_ Seems like you did not completely remove it.

Comment: I remove the app with Windows Uninstaller.

Comment: Does the command a “force” option?

Comment: I didn't understand the question

Comment: Try adding `--force` to the command…